# Plant Network model

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am looking for some help in Plant Network Optimization- as an example scenario would be to optimize the Plant network based on the below inputs and figure out best possible plants to use to service the given demand. Model should also provide some fictitious locations where we should have a plant setup and be able to turn off/on current plants based on the below inputs and constraints.

As this is an experimental study, I would like to use open solver here and wanted to see if any scholar or an academic person would like to help me out as a freelancer

Modelling Inputs
Plants  - 5 in the network across USA with a specified location
Products - 1000
Customers - 5

Attributes - Inputs:
Demand - ( Product/Plant/Customer/Month/Zip Code)
Fixed Cost( Plant)
Variable Cost( Plant/Product)
Logistics Cost( Product/Customer/Zip)
Capacity available( Plant/Month)
Capacity needed( Plant/Product/Month)

Constraints:
Capacity Needed <= Capacity available
Supply <= demand

Outputs:
Cost to serve
Logistics cost
Fixed Cost
Variable costs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem

Comment: Not sure if you want to solve a Facility Location problem, or a Transportation Problem with Fixed Costs

Comment: I think one can feed the other, if it is too much to handle we can solve one here either location or the transportation